# Ionic 2 / 3 - ion-slides dynamically change direction at runtime

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'd like to dynamically change the direction of the ion-slides component at runtime.

The problem is, whenever I change the direction the ion-slides component breaks - no errors are thrown but the slides disappear after a single swipe.

I'm guessing certain parameters are set at the component's initialization stage, and I need to readjust them somehow when I change the direction.

How should I do it?

```
<div style="height: 90%">
    <ion-slides [direction]="directionVertical ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal'">
        <ion-slide>Slide 1</ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>Slide 2</ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>Slide 3</ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</div>

<button ion-button block (click)="directionVertical = directionVertical ? false : true">Change Direction : {{ directionVertical ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal' }}</button>
```

Comment: I haven't looked into how ion-slides work but maybe you can just have a copy of your code above and show/nide the appropriate section.  Also you could simplify your logic for (click)="dv = !dv"

Comment: Regarding logic - I wanted to take into account null but it's all the same, you're right. True, that would be one solution, I didn't think of that. Thanks. I'd prefer to know how to do it with one ion-slides component though, assuming it's even possible.

Comment: Theoretically it should work, but that solution has many problems, I've written a detailed explanation here:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-slides-dynamically-change-direction-at-runtime/91884